# Easiest way to extract all city|town|village out of OSM?

Tags: openstreetmap, download

I'm not a techie and I don't have the space to download the 500GB planet OSM file and run through osmosis.  What is the easiest way for me to download all nodes of type City+Town+Village (as defined by OSM), pulling just these parameters:
•    Node ID
•    Node Latitude
•    Node Longitude
•    Key (city or town or village)
•    Name
•    Population
•    is_in:state_code
•    is_in:country_code
Please help (in a way a non-techie can understand).  I've come across literature on many ways to pull data from OSM but instructions haven't been clean enough for me to figure out.

Comment: Can you specify what you want to achieve? just the city nodes:
http://overpass-turbo.eu/s/fbT you can edit the code to obtain the other parameters youre interested in. The data is in GeoJSOn or more detailed stuff:
https://mapzen.com/data/metro-extracts/ In case you want to download all extracts you can use DownThemAll! (firefox plugin)

Comment: Thanks @RutgerH.  My end goal is to have a CSV (I can convert from geoJSON) with one line for each city/town/village.  The columns would refer to bulleted parameters listed above.  

I have tried overpass turbo and although I could get it to work for a map area, it timed out if i try to run for the whole world.  Not to mention, I can't find the syntax for how to call just the parameters I've listed.  MapZen isn't the solution for me because I need whole world.  I assume Osmosis isn't the solution for me because I can't fit a 500GB Planet file on my laptop.

Answer (score -1):

if you just want data that extracted from OSM, you can access [geofabrik](http://download.geofabrik.de/) to download your specified region.

Comment: This is just the OSM data extract for each region - isn't a solution